# How do I update certain Values from one table into another

Tags: t-sql, insert

I have two tables with seemingly unrelated data and want to update one column with the values of the other table. eg

**tArticle**

```
ID        Weight    orderId    count
57        1000      10         1
1000      500       10         3
2501      1500      10         1
13        725       10         1
758       1000      10         1
...
```

**tPackage**

```
ID        Weight    orderId
1001      0         10
1002      0         10
1003      0         10
1004      0         10
...
```

this is how it should look like after the insert:

**tPackage**

```
ID        Weight    orderId
1001      1000      10
1002      500       10
1003      500       10
1004      500       10
1005      1500      10
1006      725       10
1007      1000      10
...
```

the packages have no reference to the articles but I have one package per article and need to assign each package a weight from an article. An article can appear multiple times and its weight needs to be assigned per unit. I always have the exact number of packages.

Regarding to what I have tried I sincerely have to say that I am drawing a total blank about how to attempt this. Do i have to create a temporary table to manage this?

Comment: Join tArticle with a tally table on count>=tally.id to create duplicates. Use row_number() over (order by ID,tally.id) to create a "new" id - do this on a temp table or cte, whatever suits you. Do a corresponding id to your tPackage directly with row_number() over (order by ID). Join on the newID and update.

Add to your question create/insert scripts if you want more/faster answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to George Menoutis I figured it out, I think. Tally tables, ctes and Row_number() were all new concepts to me, so it took me a while. Here´s what I got:

```
WITH tally AS(
    SELECT N=Number, myId=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, Number), Weight
    FROM master..spt_values 
    JOIN tArticle ON count >= Number 
    WHERE type = 'P'
),
cte AS
(
    SELECT myId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), Weight
    FROM tPackage 
)
UPDATE cte SET cte.Weight = tally.Weight
FROM tally WHERE tally.myId = cte.myId
```

Will accept this as my Answer unless someone has something better